# What's the difference between a Displacement node and a Vector Displacemet node?

Tags: node-editor

I'm relatively new to Blender, and I've followed some tutorials where they use a displacement node, and some where they use a vector displacement node, and I'm not really sure what the difference is.

Comment: Here's from the official documentation - https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/vector_displacement.html#:~:text=The%20Vector%20Displacement%20node%20is,displaces%20along%20the%20surface%20normal.&text=Vector%20displacement%20maps%20can%20fully,mesh%2C%20unlike%20regular%20displacement%20maps.

Comment: Thanks, I kinda get it now